# move Command + wildcards = Bizarre Results

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, wildcard, move

I've got a pretty bizarre issue that I've come across today. I've outlined the steps to reproduce the issue below. I've also already implemented a workaround to this issue which I've posted as well, and so I'm  concerned with WHY this is happening and why I need to use the "workaround"?

**====================**
**~ Steps to Reproduce ~**
**====================**

- Create an empty folder, then create an empty file "_Generate Files.bat" in that folder.
- Inside "_Generate Files.bat" copy/paste the code below and Save.

```
echo test>"2019-10-21 15.36.11.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-21 15.40.40.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-21 16.37.34.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-21 17.59.06.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-21 17.59.12.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-21 17.59.21.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-21 17.59.38.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-21 18.05.45.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-21 19.06.48.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-24 17.36.20.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-24 19.03.26.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-30 16.12.45.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 04.37.35.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 19.22.43.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 19.22.48.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 19.22.57.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 19.22.59.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 19.23.03.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.19.49.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.22.20.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.26.27.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.26.32.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.26.40.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.26.44.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.26.45.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.29.22.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.30.51.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.32.28.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.32.37.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.32.48.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.32.51.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.34.15.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.36.26.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.36.29.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.39.49.txt"
echo test>"2019-10-31 20.40.03.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-01 01.22.28.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-01 01.22.31.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-01 01.26.15.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-01 01.27.11.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-01 03.08.07.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-01 15.15.07.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-04 22.20.42.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-04 22.39.26.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-05 15.46.28.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-05 15.46.28_1.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-05 15.46.28_2.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-05 15.46.29.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-05 15.46.29_1.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-05 15.46.29_2.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-05 15.46.29_3.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-05 15.46.30.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-05 15.58.21.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-05 15.58.22.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-05 15.58.22_1.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-05 15.58.23.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-06 22.43.29.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-06 22.43.29_1.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-06 22.43.30.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-06 22.43.30_1.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-06 22.43.30_2.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-06 22.43.30_3.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-06 22.43.30_4.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-06 22.43.31.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-06 22.43.31_1.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-06 22.43.31_2.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-07 16.18.49.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-07 16.18.49_1.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-09 14.49.26.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-09 14.49.27.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-09 14.49.27_1.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-09 14.49.27_2.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-09 14.49.28.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-09 14.49.28_1.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-09 14.49.29.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-10 20.24.19.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-11 00.02.39.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-11 15.13.51.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-11 19.45.44.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-11 22.24.08.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-11 22.32.26.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-11 22.34.43.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-11 22.35.57.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-11 22.36.21.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-11 22.38.05.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-11 22.42.31.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-12 04.52.16.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-15 21.37.01.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-15 21.37.17.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-17 17.15.17.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-18 15.51.10.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-18 15.51.40.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-18 15.51.46.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-18 16.48.58.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-18 16.49.01.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-18 16.49.03.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-18 16.49.11.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-18 16.49.30.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-18 16.49.33.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-18 16.49.35.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-18 16.49.38.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-18 16.50.05.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-18 16.50.11.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-28 19.00.59.txt"
echo test>"2019-11-28 19.01.09.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-06 18.27.12.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-06 18.27.53.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-06 18.28.36.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-06 18.28.59.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-06 21.32.19.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-06 21.34.22.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-08 02.40.25.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-09 04.28.26.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-10 14.09.05.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-10 14.09.16.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-12 14.27.19.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-13 00.58.04.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-13 15.16.43.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-13 23.35.04.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-14 14.13.37.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-15 13.41.33.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-17 11.08.46.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-17 11.08.54.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-17 17.01.03.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-17 17.01.10.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-17 21.44.07.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-18 18.57.58.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-19 16.18.14.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-19 16.36.39.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-19 16.36.47.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-19 16.36.52.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-19 16.52.24.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-19 18.34.12.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-19 18.43.26.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-20 12.27.21.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-20 13.08.47.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-20 13.11.32.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-20 13.14.17.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-21 01.05.30.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-22 19.11.07.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-22 19.44.03.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-24 20.19.44.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-24 20.19.47.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.02.54.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.03.00.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.03.03.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.09.23.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.09.56.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.10.33.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.10.38.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.10.44.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.11.10.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.11.11.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.11.25.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.11.45.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.11.51.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.13.26.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.13.29.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.13.51.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.13.58.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.14.05.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.15.29.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.15.32.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.17.04.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.17.06.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.17.17.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.17.20.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.17.33.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-25 13.17.48.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-26 13.44.15.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-26 15.49.08.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-26 17.55.57.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-26 18.26.21.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-26 18.29.01.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-26 18.29.39.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-26 18.29.47.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-26 18.32.03.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-26 19.24.15.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-26 22.53.32.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-27 02.43.19.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 15.12.38.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 15.12.41.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 15.58.26.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 15.58.33.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 15.58.38.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 15.58.42.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 15.58.59.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 15.59.02.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 16.00.13.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 16.00.16.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 16.00.18.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 17.42.13.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 18.35.56.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 18.36.04.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 19.23.03.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 19.23.07.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 19.23.13.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 19.23.16.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 19.23.18.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 19.23.31.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 19.23.36.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 19.23.43.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 20.02.10.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 20.02.16.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 20.02.25.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 20.02.36.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 20.02.46.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 20.02.52.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 21.05.48.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 22.15.35.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 22.15.36.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 22.16.05.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 22.36.18.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 22.37.13.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 22.37.20.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 22.37.23.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 22.37.25.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 22.37.27.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 22.37.43.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 22.37.47.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 22.37.52.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 22.38.41.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-28 22.38.43.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-29 00.37.38.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-29 00.37.41.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-29 00.37.44.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-29 00.37.46.txt"
echo test>"2019-12-29 00.38.07.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-03 14.51.49.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-04 13.57.21.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-05 01.01.02.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-05 01.01.30.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-06 02.58.12.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-06 04.55.12.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-06 04.55.53.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-07 01.55.07.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-08 19.13.19.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-08 19.13.44.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-08 19.13.57.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-08 19.14.15.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-08 19.14.18.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-08 19.17.16.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-08 23.24.50.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-08 23.25.19.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-08 23.25.25.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-08 23.25.40.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 00.12.27.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 00.12.32.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 00.12.34.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 00.12.36.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 00.33.32.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 20.50.10.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 20.50.15.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 20.50.17.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 21.04.32.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 21.04.37.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 21.04.39.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 21.04.43.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 21.15.25.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 21.15.36.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-09 21.56.16.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-12 19.16.32.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-13 19.06.16.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-13 22.06.34.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-14 12.34.06.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-14 16.29.56.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-14 16.29.58.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-14 16.30.05.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-14 16.30.18.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-16 13.20.15.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-16 13.20.25.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-16 13.20.27.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-16 18.07.55.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-18 23.14.01.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-18 23.14.07.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-20 00.11.20.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-20 00.11.28.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-20 00.23.04.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-20 21.17.22.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-20 21.17.58.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-20 21.19.04.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-20 21.19.57.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-20 21.21.57.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-21 01.31.46.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-22 15.34.21.txt"
echo test>"2020-01-22 18.19.55.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-11 15.46.51.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-13 14.10.18.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-14 16.00.12.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-14 16.02.33.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-14 18.39.28.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-14 18.39.35.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-14 18.39.39.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-15 14.15.01.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-15 14.17.26.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-15 16.24.44.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-15 18.45.09.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-15 18.45.50.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-15 18.46.21.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-18 17.11.50.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-18 17.11.53.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-18 17.38.11.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-18 17.38.17.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-18 17.38.25.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-18 17.38.29.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-21 20.47.44.txt"
echo test>"2020-02-28 23.28.23.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-03 15.26.45.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-03 15.27.12.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-03 16.28.37.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-03 16.35.57.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-03 16.36.35.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-03 16.36.41.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-03 16.36.45.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-09 14.56.57.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-09 14.57.11.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-09 14.57.34.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-09 14.57.40.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-11 17.58.47.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-11 19.48.22.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-20 15.56.33.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-20 16.06.19.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-20 16.06.31.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-20 16.06.51.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-20 16.06.58.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-25 13.39.33.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-25 13.39.52.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-25 13.40.03.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-25 13.40.31.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-28 20.28.23.txt"
echo test>"2020-03-28 20.28.26.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-02 14.54.13.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-03 18.05.27.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-03 18.05.28.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-03 18.05.28_1.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-03 18.05.28_2.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-03 18.05.28_3.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-03 18.05.29.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-05 17.21.26.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 16.40.07.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 16.40.13.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.24.27.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.24.31.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.25.32.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.25.39.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.25.51.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.26.07.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.26.10.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.26.19.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.26.25.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.34.20.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.34.51.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.35.17.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.35.27.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.35.36.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.35.41.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.35.45.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.35.53.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.36.02.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.36.04.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.59.46.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 17.59.57.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 18.00.04.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 18.00.13.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 18.00.19.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 18.00.28.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 18.00.33.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 18.00.41.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 18.00.51.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 18.00.59.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-23 18.01.02.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-27 01.57.34.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-27 19.37.21.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-27 19.38.46.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-27 19.39.46.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-27 19.39.48.txt"
echo test>"2020-04-27 19.39.53.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-04 16.35.51.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-04 16.36.11.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-05 18.37.54.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-05 18.38.55.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-05 18.39.08.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-05 18.39.40.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-05 18.39.46.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-05 18.39.48.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-05 18.40.02.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-05 18.40.08.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-05 18.40.10.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-05 18.40.17.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-05 19.47.49.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-28 19.10.13.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-28 19.10.17.txt"
echo test>"2020-05-28 19.10.19.txt"
echo test>"2020-06-01 18.32.04.txt"
```

- Now execute "_Generate Files.bat" which will create 394 text files in the folder.
- Now open a command window from that folder and run the following commands...

```
mkdir 2007
move 2007* 2007\
```

- Check the "2007" folder which should now contain the file "2019-10-31 20.26.32.txt".

But why did that file get moved into that folder? There is no "2007*" in the filename anywhere!

**==================**
**~ Bonus Bizarreness ~**
**==================**

- With the command window still open, run the following commands...

```
cmd /v:on
for /l %g in (2000,1,2020) do (set year=%g& if exist "!year!*" if not exist "!year!" mkdir !year! & move !year!* !year!\)
```

Now all the text files are moved into several folders spanning from "2000-2020". But they should have only been moved into two folders, 2019 and 2020, since the filenames only contain those two matching prefixes that the move command would have used to move those files. I don't understand why they are being moved into incorrect folders.

**=============**
**~ Workaround ~**
**=============**

To workaround this issue, I added a hyphen after the year, "!year!-" instead of "!year!"...

```
move 2007-* 2007\
```

Which instead of moving the file like it did previously, now gives the output..
*"A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found."*
which is what it should be telling me without using the hyphen.

Same thing with the "for loop" command...

```
cmd /v:on
for /l %g in (2000,1,2020) do (set year=%g& if exist "!year!-*" if not exist "!year!" mkdir !year! & move !year!-* !year!\)
```

Please note that this only happens when ALL of these files are in the same folder. For example, I take the first 10 text files in the folder, and move them into a separate folder, I can then run the commands WITHOUT the hyphen "2007*", and it will correctly move the 10 text files into a "2019" folder like it should.

So can anyone explain why this bizarre behavior is happening? In all the hundreds of batch scripts I've written, this is the first time I've ever come across this issue. I've used this same script to move files for quite some time and it's always worked just fine. However, this is the first time I've ever used it with this many files in one folder. But I have no idea why the amount of files would change it's behaviour???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Check the "2007" folder which should now contain the file "2019-10-31 20.26.32.txt".
>
> But why did that file get moved into that folder? There is no "2007*" in the filename anywhere!

Presumably you have [SFNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) (short filenames) enabled on that volume, and the short 8.3 name of `2019-10-31 20.26.32.txt` happens to be `2007CE~1.TXT`.

Confusingly enough, the filename wildcards check *both* long and short names.

```
C:\etc>dir /b 2007*
2019-10-31 20.26.32.txt

C:\etc>dir /x | find "2007"
06/08/2020  08:45 PM                 6 2007CE~1.TXT 2019-10-31 20.26.32.txt
```

Comment: 8.3 filenames were EXACTLY what the issue was. I was originally testing from a folder on my desktop which has "8.3 filenames" enabled on that drive. But I just tested on another drive which has 8.3 filenames disabled, and everything works as expected now. It's frustrating because at one point I had even contimplated 8.3 filenames possibly being the issue, but I disregarded it because I thought you had to actually specify an 8.3 filename before it would actually be used. But as you stated, using wildcards will check "both" long and short filenames. Thank You for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

As user [dxiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5538420) already correctly pointed out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62273773), [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) are matched against both long and short file names (when the latter are available).

To work around that issue use the [`where` command](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html), which only returns long file paths/names, together with [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html):

```cmd
rem // Capture the output of the `where` command line:
for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
    rem / // This returns a pure list of LONG file paths/names: ^& ^
        set "PATHEXT=" ^& where "D:\path\to\target:2007*.txt"
') do (
    rem // Process currently iterated item (just echo it out here):
    echo Full path of processed item: "%%F"
)
```

Since `where` also regards the [`PATHEXT` system variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) and could therefore return unwanted additional items, it needs to be temporarily cleared. Since `for /F` executes the command line behind `in` in a new Command Prompt instance, this does not affect the instance the batch file runs in.

To recurse into sub-directories too, you can use `where /R "D:\path\to\target" "2007*.txt"`.